# Convert numbers to letters in Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on Jasper Reports using IReport. I want to convert the amount to Words such as 1500 to One thousand five hundred.

I retrieve the numbers from the database and print it on the report. At the end I want the final value to be converted to Words.

Is there any method in Jasper Reports to do this? I have found a Java class to do that. If there's any method in Jasper report, how can I call Java method from jasper report to convert the numbers to letters

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not such method in JasperReports.

I'd think you'd have to calculate the "final value" in Java, convert it and pass that as a parameter to the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *scriptlet* to solve your problem. The samples is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html#scriptlet) and [here](http://blog.sacaluta.com/2007/07/jasperreports-scriptlet-example.html).

The sample:

the scriptlet class extended [JRDefaultScriptlet](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDefaultScriptlet.html):

```java
public class ReportScriptlet extends net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet 

    public static String convertIntToWords(int value) {

        IConverter converter = new ConverterImpl(value);

        return converter.convert();
    }
}
```

set scriptlet in report and its usage:

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ...
scriptletClass="package.ReportScriptlet">  

...

   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.convertIntToWords($F{sum})]]></textFieldExpression>
```